# How can add double quotes in string using python

Tags: python, json, api

The problem is displaying the "values" I get from the json in double quotes.

> ex: "9000-123"

Would you help me with this topic?

empty = {'reservation-num': '9000-123', 'receipt-num': '001', 'bond-date': '12.12.2000', 'receipt-time': '20:20', 'numberof-items': '1,00', 'item-num': '10.234.09', 'item-designation': 'Hühnersuppe', 'vat-rate-in-percent': '16,00', 'gross-unit-price-of-the-item': '9,50', 'total-gross-amount-of-the-receipt': '9,50', 'currency-sembol': 'DEM', 'clerk-num': '12', 'clerk-name': 'Elif'}

```
for emp in h3cashin_data:
    var_reservation = emp["reservation-num"]
    csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
```

Comment: Why do you use csv?

Comment: so when you say "displaying", do you mean you want to print `"9000-123"` to the console, but with double quotes and not single quotes? or to write it to the csv using the writer you have in your code snippet? It would be a lot clearer if you could add what behaviour you are currently getting and what the final result of a small toy example should look like. (maybe check out the [mcve] page too)

Comment: I need to convert the data I receive as json to csv format.
Here, each value in csv format must be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: You should configure `csvwriter` to alway quote fields, rather than only when the contents of the field requires quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you,

```
for emp in h3cashin_data:
    var_reservation = emp["reservation-num"]
    csvwriter.writerow(['"'+value+'"' for value in emp.values()])
```

Comment: I'have a little problem. It returns """9000-123""" but it should be "9000-123"

Comment: try this then
`csvwriter.writerow([value for value in emp.values()])`